# angular ngTable rest pagination filter issues

Tags: angularjs, grails, ngtable

```
'use strict';
function NumbersCtrl(DAO, $rootScope, $scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
$rootScope.getAllNumbers = function () {
    //get all

    $rootScope.errors.errorMessages=[];
     DAO.query({appName: $rootScope.appConfig.appName, token: $rootScope.appConfig.token, controller: 'numbers', action: 'list'},   
                $rootScope.loadingSite=true,
                function (result) {
         $rootScope.numberss = result;

         $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,           // count per page
            sorting: {
                id : 'desc' // initial sorting
            }
     }, {
        total: $rootScope.numberss.length,
     getData: function($defer, params) {
            var putIt  = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')( $rootScope.numberss, params.orderBy()): id;
            params.total(putIt.length);
               $defer.resolve(putIt.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            // $rootScope.numberss = sendIt;
            //$rootScope.numberss=putIt.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            //$defer.resolve(putIt.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

            //$rootScope.numberss = putIt;
     }
     });
}
```

I am working on grails-arrested-plugin and have hit a stumbling block so anyone advice appreciated:

So above is my controller call - I have a few commented out attempts to get information back paginated - ordered with filtering.

so far I have got semi pagination attempt working to work and if I use :

```
$rootScope.numberss=putIt.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
```

The above actually only return the first 10 results but no pages ..

```
$defer.resolve(putIt.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
```

does not appear to be working but then again this isn't the documented way of doing things since the DAO is a rest call :

```
use strict';
angular.module('services',['ngResource','ngTable']).
    factory('DAO', function($resource){
        return $resource('/:appName/:controller/:action',{
            format:'json', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},{
          ..
            'query': {method:'GET', params:{appName:'@appName', controller:'@controller', action:'@action', token:'@token'}, isArray: true, timeout:20000},
```

Comment: got it working will update with an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have pagination now working across two ways of calling / pros - cons ? from what I have read the first explained method does less calls:

Besides the fix actual filtering is still not working - so if anyone can point out what needs to be done to fix the filter it would be great:

So page initialiases

```
<div data-ng-controller="NumbersCtrl"  data-ng-init="getAllNumbers()">
```

Controller then does a function on it

```
$rootScope.getAllNumbers = function () {
        //get all
        $rootScope.errors.errorMessages=[];
         DAO.query({appName: $rootScope.appConfig.appName, token: $rootScope.appConfig.token, controller: 'numbers', action: 'list'},   
            $rootScope.loadingSite=true,
            function (result) {
                $rootScope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10,           // count per page
                    sorting: {
                        id : 'desc' // initial sorting
                    }
                }, {
                    total: result.length,
                    getData: function($defer, params) {
                        $rootScope.numberss  = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(result, params.orderBy()): id;
                        //params.total(putIt.length);
                        $defer.resolve($rootScope.numberss.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        $rootScope.numberss=($rootScope.numberss.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                });
                $rootScope.loadingSite=false;   
            },
            function (error) {
                $rootScope.errors.showErrors = true;
                $rootScope.errors.showServerError = true;
                $rootScope.errors.errorMessages.push(''+error.status+' '+error.data);
                $rootScope.loadingSite=false;
             });

    };
```

I have ended up using this method since I do not initialise anything:

```
<div data-ng-controller="NumbersCtrl" >
```

and calling this controller action (as per default instructions of ngtable - i.e. its default calls which would have also existed on the above method:

```
$rootScope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10,           // count per page
    sorting: {
        id : 'desc' // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        DAO.query({appName: $rootScope.appConfig.appName, token: $rootScope.appConfig.token, controller: 'numbers', action: 'list'},    
            $rootScope.loadingSite=true,
                function (result) {
                    $rootScope.numberss=result;
                    var putIt  = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($rootScope.numberss, params.orderBy()): id;
                    params.total(putIt.length);
                    $defer.resolve(putIt.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    $rootScope.numberss=(putIt.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    $rootScope.loadingSite=false;   
                },
                function (error) {
                    $rootScope.errors.showErrors = true;
                    $rootScope.errors.showServerError = true;
                    $rootScope.errors.errorMessages.push(''+error.status+' '+error.data);
                    $rootScope.loadingSite=false;
                });
    }
});
```

The actual fix appears to be the final call under defer:

```
$defer.resolve($rootScope.numberss.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                            $rootScope.numberss=($rootScope.numberss.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
```

The html page containing this table call here:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testingarrested/blob/master/grails-app/views/numbers/list.gsp

The angular controller here:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testingarrested/blob/master/web-app/js/NumbersCtrl.js

I will update the branch in a moment which will contain all of this -

So to summarize pagination working filtering not - it must be something minor now..

Edit: To finalise - everything is working I was missing:

```
putIt = params.filter ? $filter('filter')( putIt, params.filter()) :  putIt;
```

under first putIt - search/pagination working across a rest call